# Struggling to get the text centered

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Can someone help me get this text centered please,

I have tried changing the layout width, height and padding but only managed to make it worse,

```
<com.github.mmin18.widget.FlexLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:background="@color/login_bg" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView 
    android:id="@id/logo" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/logo_main" 
    app:layout_centerX="50%" 
    app:layout_centerY="30%" />

  <EditText 
    android:textSize="18.0sp" 
    android:textColorHint="#ff4d4d4d"                 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@id/edit_code" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:layout_width="341.32812dip" 
    android:layout_height="46.0dip" 
    android:hint="@string/active_code" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:inputType="text" 
    app:layout_centerX="50%" 
    app:layout_top="logo.bottom + parent.height/20" />

<Button 
    android:textSize="18.0sp" 
    android:id="@id/btn_reset" 
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:layout_width="160.0dip" 
    android:layout_height="36.0dip" 
    android:text="@string/reset" 
    android:textAllCaps="false" 
    app:layout_left="edit_code.left + 2dp" 
    app:layout_top="edit_code.bottom + 8dp" />

<Button 
    android:textSize="18.0sp" 
    android:id="@id/btn_login"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:layout_width="160.0dip" 
    android:layout_height="36.0dip" 
    android:text="@string/login" 
    android:textAllCaps="false" 
    app:layout_right="edit_code.right" 
    app:layout_top="edit_code.bottom + 8dp" />

<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@id/pb" 
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:layout_width="22.0dip" 
    android:layout_height="22.0dip"                         
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/login_progress" 
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/btn_login" 
    app:layout_centerY="btn_login.centerY" 
    app:layout_right="btn_login.right-0.0556*screen.height" />

<TextView 
    android:textSize="22.0sp" 
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:id="@id/change_login" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Please click here to login" 
    android:paddingStart="3.0dip" 
    android:paddingEnd="3.0dip" 
    app:layout_right="btn_login.right" 
    app:layout_top="btn_login.bottom + 8dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
    android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox" android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@id/statement_check" 
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_36dp" 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_36dp" 
    app:layout_height="btn_reset.height" 
    app:layout_left="btn_reset.left" 
    app:layout_top="change_login.bottom + 8dp" 
    app:layout_width="btn_reset.height" />

<TextView 
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"         
    android:id="@id/statement" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/state_all" 
    app:layout_left="statement_check.right + 8dp" 
    app:layout_right="btn_login.right" 
    app:layout_top="statement_check.top" />

</com.github.mmin18.widget.FlexLayout>
```

I thought removing the padding would help or changing it to fill content would help but the text just disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you got a better answer if you post the XML code of your application.
Usually, to get the text of an item centered you just need to use the "gravity" property.
In your XML file, search for the component with the text you want to center and add the following to it's properties:

`android:gravity="center"`

Comment: Thank you for replying i also tried adding that but didn't make a difference either, i have a feeling something is conflicting.

Comment: @jafo666 I need to know first: you want the text inside a component centered or the component centered?

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties of TextViews that might help you.

- First is the `gravity` attribute. This attribute would center your text within the boundary of your TextView. Therefore, no matter how large or how small your actual TextView is, the text would always be in the center of it. Here's an implementation:

  ```
  android:gravity="center"
  ```
- There's also the `layout_gravity` attribute, this attribute positions your TextView relative to the nearest parent view. It is important to note that this attribute **does not center the text**, rather, it centers the whole TextView. Here's an implementation:

  ```
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  ```

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) to learn more.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!